# Can't find an internal method in a React container component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get AJAX-retrieved data into a parent React component so it can be fed down to a child component. I'm using the popular pattern for this defined [here](https://gist.github.com/chantastic/fc9e3853464dffdb1e3c) where a comment list is used as the example:

components/CommentList.js

```
import React from 'React';

export class CommentList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return <ul> {this.props.comments.map(renderComment)} </ul>;
  }
  renderComment({body, author}) {
    return <li>{body}—{author}</li>;
  }
}
```

components/CommentListContainer.js

```
import React from 'React';
import { CommentList } from './CommentList';


export class CommentListContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { comments: [] }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://get/some/api",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(comments) {
        this.setState({comments: comments});
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }
  render() {
    return <CommentList comments={this.state.comments} />;
  }
}
```

index.js: the entry point for webpack

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { CommentListContainer } from './components/CommentListContainer';

window.React = React;

render(
  <CommentListContainer />,
  document.getElementById('nav__react-target')
)
```

When doing all this, I get the following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: renderComment is not defined`

I've move the methods around as well as tweaked the importing of dependencies in various spots with no luck. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have unguarded references to sibling methods with ES2015 classes (as you do in Java / C#, etc.) - instead you need to explicitly reference `this` to get at the methods of the class:

```
render() {
  // I changed map(renderComment) to map(this.renderComment)
  return <ul>{this.props.comments.map(this.renderComment)}</ul>;
}
```

Comment: Sean Viera: makes sense...that got things working. Thanks!